# R scraping with rvest, treated as mobile device rather than computer device

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape a website with rvest package.

there is a problem: when you type in web = read_html("www.somewebsite.com") sometimes you get a html which is aiming for mobile device.(so the url becoming m.somewebsite.com)

so the server consider you as a mobile, not a computer.

Is there a way to make the server treat me as a computer rather than a mobile? Any further operation with mobile site is hard. Or can we control the request in some way so that we can control the way server treat us? Sometimes we want to be treated as mobile, whereas sometimes we want to be treated as computer.

The method may not limited to package rvest, we can use httr or Rcurl

Since Kim want an example, here I gave a concrete example!

```
library(rvest)
sina_url = "https://www.sina.com.cn"
sina = html_session(sina_url)
sina_sport = sina%>%follow_link("体育")%>%html_nodes("li:nth-child(1) h2")%>%html_text()
```

the response of the last line is :

```
Navigating to http://m.sina.com.cn/m/sinasports.shtml
```

clearly, the server thinks I am using mobile to connect!

Unfortunately, This page has chinese, "体育" means "sports"
I found this problem when I gave a lesson to my student.

Comment: That's really interesting... can you show us an example webpage that ran into this problem?

Comment: Usually it's a different URL, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language) vs https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language) but some sites may use your user agent string or somesuch to decide what to serve you. You can customize your request with httr.

Comment: Possible solution is to send a header with browser info!

Comment: Yes, I have a concrete example! But is has some chinese which may not be reproducible for all people, I found this problem when I give a lesson to my student

Comment: @Kim I have edited my question, you will see a example using the code

Comment: @amrrs thanks! can you be more specific? at least with some function and a simple example, I will test it with complicated cases

Comment: See `?httr::user_agent`

Comment: can't use `httr::user_agent()` with `read_html`. do `options(HTTPUserAgent = "splashr::ua_win10_chrome")` before your `read_html()` (or use your own user agent if you don't want to install `splashr`)